# Как расставить корабли в игре "Морской бой"

Tags: java, android, разработка-игр, морской-бой

У меня есть массив с массивами, в которых хранятся числа:

```
    int[][] pole = new int[][]
        {
                {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
        };
```

И код который добавляет корабли в этот массив (поле):

```
//set 1x4 ship
    int j = new Random().nextInt(6)+1;
    if(new Random().nextBoolean())
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        pole[j][i]=1;
        pole[j-1][i]=2;
        pole[j+1][i]=2;
        if(i==3){
            pole[j-1][i+1]=2;
            pole[j+1][i+1]=2;
            pole[j][i+1]=2;
        }
        }
    else
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            pole[i][j]=1;
            if(i!=0&&j!=6){
                pole[i-1][j+1]=2;
                pole[i+1][j+1]=2;
                pole[i][j+1]=2;
            }
            if(i!=0){
                pole[i-1][j-1]=2;
                pole[i+1][j-1]=2;
                pole[i][j-1]=2;
                pole[i+1][j]=2;
            }
        }

        while(true){
            if(new Random().nextBoolean())
                if(
                        pole[j][0]!=1&&pole[j][0]!=2&&
                        pole[j][1]!=1&&pole[j][1]!=2&&
                        pole[j][2]!=1&&pole[j][2]!=2
                ){ for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                        pole[j][i] = 1;
                        pole[j - 1][i] = 2;
                        pole[j + 1][i] = 2;
                        if (i == 2) {
                            pole[j - 1][i + 1] = 2;
                            pole[j + 1][i + 1] = 2;
                            pole[j][i + 1] = 2;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                }
            else
                if(
                        pole[0][j]!=2&&pole[0][j]!=1&&
                        pole[1][j]!=2&&pole[1][j]!=1&&
                        pole[2][j]!=2&&pole[2][j]!=1
                ){
                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                    pole[i][j]=1;
                    if(i!=0&&j!=6){
                        pole[i-1][j+1]=2;
                        pole[i+1][j+1]=2;
                        pole[i][j+1]=2;
                    }
                    if(i!=0){
                        pole[i-1][j-1]=2;
                        pole[i+1][j-1]=2;
                        pole[i][j-1]=2;
                        pole[i+1][j]=2;
                    }
                }
                break;}
        }
```

Но этот код при выполнение начинает зависать. Я пытался пол часа довести его до нормального состояния и у меня все равно не получилось сделать так, чтобы он не зависал.
Подскажите пожалуйста, может кто-нибудь делал морской бой под Android, как вы делали система автоустановки кораблей?

Comment: 1. А зачем вам собственно `while(true)`, тем более что сразу по окончания "тела" следует `break`?

Comment: @nick_n_a этот break в блоке else if {\*тут*\}

Comment: 2. А у вас случайная точка это `j` ?  Ну так она всегда занята - значит бесконечный цикл. Вы не выбрали новое место, да и не понятно, почему только одна координата рандом, а не две.

Comment: 3. По поводу расстановки. Есть решение "влоб" по-проще. Я не вижу что оно у вас реализовано в полном обьёме, но учтите - при увеличении заполнености поля - увеличивается частота промахов random - как следвиствие - даже на современном ПК поле может считаться дого. Старые ПК влоб у меня 5 минут 36 карт тусовали. Кораблики - ну за несколько секунд должны расставится, главное что бы "запретная" комбинация не попалась (т.е. такой случай когда новый корабль "негде ставить". Не помню есть ли такое в этой игре, т.к. человек этот случай бысто определяет и выбрасывает.

Comment: Поэтому [3] при рандомном выборе позиции, лучше сначало считать возможные позиции, и выбирать вероятную из возможных, а не возможную из вероятных (т.е. ткнули в точку и проверяем можно ли тут поставить). Тогда алгоритм работает быстрее, и если есть "запретная" комбинация - это будет сразу ясно, а не спустя длительное время.

Comment: Ещё совет - вместо true - ставьте "число попыток", дайте 100 или 1000 попыток - если нет - выход из цикла - тогда не будет повисаний в бесконечных циклах.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Когда-то давно писал морской бой на C#, вот по-быстрому перевел на java, код рабочий, но тестов не было, возможно оптимизации нужны. Алгоритм нашел где-то в интернете.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Battleship {



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Battleship battleship = new Battleship();
        int[][] botField = new int[10][10];
        battleship.ships(botField);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
                System.out.print(botField[i][k]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public boolean freedom(int x, int y, int[][] Pole) {

        int dx, dy;

        if ((x >= 0) & (x < 10) & (y >= 0) & (y < 10) && ((Pole[x][y] == 0) || (Pole[x][y] == 2))) {
            for (int i = -1; i <= 1; i++) {
                for (int j = -1; j <= 1; j++) {
                    dx = x + i;
                    dy = y + j;
                    if ((dx >= 0) & (dx < 10) & (dy >= 0) & (dy < 10) && (Pole[dx][dy] == 1)) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }


    public void ships(int[][] Pole) {
        int x, y, kx, ky;
        boolean B;
        Random random = new Random();

        for (int N = 3; N >= 0; N--) {
            for (int M = 0; M <= 3 - N; M++) {
                do {
                    x = random.nextInt(10);
                    y = random.nextInt(10);
                    kx = random.nextInt(2);
                    if (kx == 0) {
                        ky = 1;
                    } else {
                        ky = 0;
                    }
                    B = true;
                    for (int j = 0; j <= N; j++) {
                        if (!(freedom(x + kx * j, y + ky * j, Pole))) {
                            B = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (B) {
                        for (int k = 0; k <= N; k++) {
                            Pole[x + kx * k][y + ky * k] = 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
                while (!(B));
            }
        }

    }

}
```